# Calculate the mean and Taylor Series expansion of theta and the range

Tags: random-variables, taylor-expansion

The range, $r$, of a cannon projectile under the influence of gravity, $g$. It is fired with a velocity, $v$. Its range is determined by the angle that it's barrel makes with the ground, theta. Given $g = 9.8 m/s$ and $v = \sqrt{980} m/s$. Theta is a random variable uniformly distributed between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I know that the range can be found using $r =  V^2 . \frac{sin(2\theta)}{g}$ which is $r=100sin(2\theta)$ once simplify. 
So my question is how would I find the mean and Taylor Series expansion of the range and theta?

Edited: more context added.

Comment: What is "range" in this context?

Comment: Do you mean $g=9.8\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$?

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: @robjohn yes, should be sin x, cos x, -sin x, -cos x, sin x, cos x, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** use the Taylor Series
$$
\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
**Hint 2:** the mean of $\sin(2\theta)$ over $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2\theta)\,\mathrm{d\theta}
&=\left.-\frac1\pi\cos(2\theta)\,\right|_0^{\pi/2}\\[6pt]
&=\frac2\pi
\end{align}
$$

Comment: so from that, i calculated to be 0.6366. But just multiple 100 to it, then its 63.66? So the mean would be 63.66

Comment: @OrangePineapple: that looks right.